# my acting is over the top again. ;^P

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does ";^P" mean? Google search led to "P!nk" and my question remains unresolved.

Sam Harris (American neuroscientist, the author of *The End of Faith*) liked (Jim Carrey tweeted):

> Nightmare-in-chief Donald Trump assembled a cast of freaks so cartoonishly evil they strain credulity.Don't **ever say my acting is over the top again. ;^P**

[image]

Comment: It's just an emote/emoticon/emoji (whatever you call it) for 'stuck out tongue': 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an emoticon of someone sticking out their tongue while winking.  The `^` is supposed to be a nose.